# Making changes to User Add Page description in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on django.And have created a custom user model for sign up.But in the add page there a description which I want to change,have a look at the red mark in the pic [image: pic]
And my admin file look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    summary="hi"
    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser','is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )




admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

What should I add to my admin file and where so that I change it??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a lot I have found an answer to your question.

So what you have to do first is add a line :

`add_form_template='add_form.html'`

to your admin file so your admin file would look like this now :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    summary="hi"
    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser','is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that go to the templates folder and add a html file with name : `add_form.html`

And then in the `add_form.html` file add following code :

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}


{% block form_top %}
<p>Type here what ever you want to add in that red mark.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Save it and then you can see the change which you were expecting

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do this however it's not super straightforward. I recommend reading the official Django docs on the admin page and particularly at the part about customising the Django templates:

[You can check this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)